# KeyError when retrieving value from Flask session

Tags: jquery, ajax, python-3.x, session, flask

I have a Flask application that stores some values in a Database. These come from an HTML form. Some of these are added to Flask's session, using the following code:

`session['userID']=str(cur_var.getvalue())`

I have a debug HTML page that only shows whatever is stored in the current session. The code to render this page is as follows:

```
@app.route('/debug/')
def debug():
    return str(session)
```

Once I open this page,

```
<securecookiesession {'usercoord': 7.0,'userid': '53.0'}></securecookiesession>
```

For what I understand, my session definitely has a `userid` key.

However, when my Flask application is on another (unrendered) URL that tries to retrieve the userID from the current session:
`new_address.append(float(session['userid']))`

I get the following error:

```
<title>KeyError: 'userid' // Werkzeug Debugger</title>
```

Furthermore, I made a very simple webpage that should only print `session['userID']`. I use the following code in my Flask application:

```
@app.route('/print/')
def printing():
    return render_template('print.html', printing=session['userid'])
```

And this is the print.html template:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
{{ printing }}
{% endblock %}
```

This yields the following error:

```
builtins.KeyError
KeyError: 'userid'
```

I already tried this same logic on a much smaller application, and it worked fine. Where could my error be here?

Thank you very much for any help you can provide.

P.S.
If it is of any use, I am handling the interaction between the webpages and my Flask application with jQuery and using AJAX to post the data.

**UPDATE**

After remaking the project to reduce it to a much simpler one, I have found that sometimes (for a reason I do not understand), adding a new value to the Flask session will not work. For example, if I include this line of code:

`session['coordid']=float(cur_var.getvalue())`

And check in my print.html page the value of `str(session)`, I do not see the key `coordid`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has to do with how AJAX is asynchronous. If you call two different jQuery functions, each with an AJAX call, chances are, one will request data that has not been processed.

In this case, you have a function that makes an AJAX call, which Python catches. The Python application takes the data from the call and stores it to the database. At the same time, there is another AJAX call which Python also takes care of. However, because not all information has been finished processing in the first call, you get the `KeyError`.

I tried several things to fix this:

- Using callbacks; however, as Lazaris (2012) notes in his post [Callback Functions in JavaScript](https://www.impressivewebs.com/callback-functions-javascript/), "if the function included some kind of asynchronous execution (like an Ajax call or an animation), then the callback would execute after the asynchronous action begins, but possibly before it finishes."
- Calling the second function in the AJAX success callback, but this did not work.
- Finally, the solution was to add the following code in the Python application. Before executing the function that depended on a value being added to session, check that this value exists:

  `count = 1000
        while not session['coordid'] and count:
            count -= 1`